# Changing the css of objects in a array

Tags: jquery

I'm woking on a jQuery personal project and I created an array and trying to edit the position of each object in the array with .css but Im getting an error.  I feel like Im doing something simple wrong.

http://codepen.io/mat148/pen/KwMbZR

The line in question is:

```
$(circleArray[5]).css('top','5px');
```

Comment: Does `circleArray[5]` exist?

Comment: shouldn't that be circleArray[**a**] or `circle` ?

Comment: Shomz it would exist if it got past this line.

Comment: gp circle is the actual object that im passing in but I should be able to access it circleArray[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
//global var
var circleArray=[];

$(window).load(function() {
    var circle = '<div class="circle"></div>';
    $(window).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 99) {
            var circleNum = parseInt( prompt("input number of elements wanted"),10 ) ;
            for(var a=0; a<circleNum;a++ ){
                var $circle = $(circle);
                $circle.css('top','5px').appendTo('.holder');
                circleArray.push($circle);
            }
            console.log(circleArray);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't think of adjusting the element and appending in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to set the css top of each circle being added, you can just change the value as you append it to the holder.

```
$(circle).appendTo('.holder').css('top', '5px');
```